# How to not use absolute positioning CSS

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm currently working on an old website that was created with some old crappy WYSIWYG editor. I'm new to web-dev and still trying to get my head around positioning elements properly. My current issue is, from what I have read, using absolute positioning is BAD, but how would you change this?

So this is the old code:

```
 <div id="wb_Text1" 
    style="margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    left:187px;
    top:24px;
    width:83px;
    height:147px;
    text-align:left;
    z-index:1;
    border:0px #C0C0C0 solid;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    background-color:transparent;
">
<div style="font-family:'.Helvetica Neue DeskInterface';font-size:15px;color:#000000;">
  <div style="text-align:left">
    <span style="font-family:Arial;font-size:43px;color:#FFFFFF;">
        <strong>W</strong>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align:left">
    <span style="font-family:Arial;font-size:43px;color:#FFFFFF;">
        <strong>A</strong>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align:left">
    <span style="font-family:Arial;font-size:43px;color:#FFFFFF;">
        <strong>C</strong>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And what I have come up with to replace it is:

HTML

```
<div class="logo-ul">
  <ul>
    <li>W</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>C</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.logo-ul {
list-style-type: none;
color: white;
font-size: 2em;
z-index:24;
float: right;
margin-right: 80%;
}
```

Which looks fine until you collapse the window and it falls apart :( lol.

You can see what I'm doing here http://media.wacmotorcycles.co.uk/

How should I be writing this please?

Thanks.

Comment: So do you want WAC in same position when you shrink the screen?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, yes. It should be considered part of the logo really along with the image.

Comment: Would you consider using bootstrap? That way you could make the entire site mobile friendly.

Comment: Maybe I should have looked at the site before commenting. Disregard what I said

Comment: I have been considering Bootstrap or Foundation and my plan is to convert this whole site to a mobile friendly wordpress site, so that in future they can update news and images without outside help. But honestly this is a learning experience for me after making a couple of HTML sites in the 90's and playing with a few Wordpress themes ;). Currently I'm just trying to set up a gallery and blog behind the existing HTML site to get them in up and running with the self editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `#logo` to

```
#logo {
    max-width: 165px;
    max-height: 171px;
    margin: 0.75em 0;
    float: left;
}
```

And, `.logo-ul` to

```
.logo-ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    z-index: 24;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: That works, thanks. So you have to tell all elements you want in a row to float:left; to keep them in the same row?

Comment: @DarrylMorley In your case, I think, float: left; is  a good idea. but, in other cases we also use display: inline-block; for example in navigation menu

Comment: Thanks for answering this question.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing inherently wrong with absolute positioning. If used incorrectly, it can have unexpected results when working with responsive layouts.

In your specific case, the **W A C** might be better implemented as part of the logo image itself rather than text. It's not offering any semantic or SEO benefit to include the letters in a list. Short of that, this is one way to implement what I think you're after:

```css
.logo {
  height: 6rem;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.logo-letter {
  display: block;
  height: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <span class="logo-letter">W</span>
  <span class="logo-letter">A</span>
  <span class="logo-letter">C</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking this myself. I did need to understand how to position the elements properly anyway though. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm curious if you don't mind? Why you would use span instead of the ul I have?

Comment: 4 parts personal preference and 1 part semantics. It doesn't feel like a "list" to me. The letters don't seem to have any value on their own, and I typically use `<span>` to represent smaller parts of a whole.